# Update all documents field entry

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I have an ElasticSearch index: `example` This index has types as dates in `YYYYMMDD` format. For example, example/20190810 is an index with a type that contains documents inserted on 20190810. The index doesn't have a field with a date, so I added a field. Now what I'd like to do is take all documents for each type and insert the date as the _type. Is there a way to do that?

```
For example:
_type: 20190810,
volume: 22,
created: 20190810 <-- Date field I added to copy its type
```

Comment: What version of elastic are you using? Newer versions of allow only one type mapping per index

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I think the answer is that you can't/shouldn't do this.

In newer versions of Elastic, there will only be allowed one type. Even if you could update _type on an existing document, ES7+ will only allow one type per index.

Most fields are fair game, but as far as I know, _type can't be modified after creation. You can verify this with this script.

```
POST example/_update_by_query
{
  "script": {
    "lang": "painless",
    "source": "ctx._type = ctx._source.date"
  }
}
```

Which outputs

```
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
        "reason": "Modifying [_type] not allowed"
      }
    ],
    "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
    "reason": "Modifying [_type] not allowed"
  },
  "status": 400
}
```

I tested this with ES6. ES7 Will give you an error about having multiple types on an index.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Miek's answer, but perhaps we could propose an alternative way to achieve what you are trying to do with the _type field. You could add the information to a new field in the documents and would not run into the issue of having multiple type in the same index (you'd have multiple value for a field instead)

If i guess you do so to be able to GET you data using the index/type syntax in your query, i would simply recommend to use the search/query apis to get the data from a given day.

Could you edit the question to include more context on what you are trying to achieve?

(note: reputation too low to comment)